# Laravel belongsToMany not returning the related data

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have the following relationship bellow the question.
This is the data I have in the database:

`ID      page_id  app_id
96      1        2
97      1        3
98      1        6
99      1        7`

this will return the page, but NOT the related `apps`

```
 $page = App\Page::find(1)->first();
 print_r($page->apps);// this has no results
```

this is the class maps, I have 2 combinations inside where you see "also not working":

```
class Page extends Model
{
    protected $table = "pages";
    //protected $appends = array('apps');//also not working
    protected $with = array('apps');//


    public function apps(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\App','page_apps','page_id','app_id')->withPivot('page_id');

      //return $this->belongsToMany('App\App','page_apps','page_id','app_id');//also not working
    }

    public function getAppsAttribute($value){
        return $value;
    }
}


class App extends Model
{
    protected $table = "apps";
    public $timestamps = true;
}


class PageApps extends Model
{
    protected $table = "page_apps";
    public $timestamps = true;
}
```

Comment: just checking first. are you sure the table for the relationship is named `page_apps` not `page_app`?

Comment: Is your page_apps a pivot table?

Comment: @jamesjaya yes.

Comment: @BalrajAllam I don't know, probably not, can u explain? thanks

Comment: what is the relationship between page and apps? I mean, does one page has many apps or many pages has many apps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove this function, it overrides the `->apps` for page

```
public function getAppsAttribute($value){
    return $value;
}
```